# Запуск php-скрипта каждую секунду

Tags: linux, bash

Каким образом нормально запускать php-скрипт каждую секунду без бесконечных циклов? Сейчас использую решение на bash с использованием командой nohup, но не нравится мне этот бесконечный цикл...

Запускаю командой:

```
nohup /path/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

script.sh:

```
while true; do 
php -f /path/script.php
sleep 1
done
```

Почему-то мне кажется, что это ненормально. Возможно ошибаюсь.

Comment: нормально. либо в самом PHP скрипте сделать бесконечный цикл с задержкой.

Comment: крон в помощь...

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц, в чём отличие крона от моего способа? Там тот же бесконечный цикл или я что-то не знаю?)

Comment: Отличия не значительны, если вы на 100% уверенны в вашем скрипте. Даже наоборот...крон сожрет немного больше чем ваш скрипт. Но тут тогда вопрос в другом: что будет если ваш скрипт вылетит? кто позаботится о нем, о его перезапуске?...

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, ТС хочет `запускать php-скрипт каждую секунду`. Кроном так нельзя. Минимально - минута

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл — вполне нормальный вариант, но стоит подумать/помнить о некоторых вещах:

1. скрипт запускает php не **раз** в секунду, а **через** секунду. В большинстве случаев это не критично, но об этом стоит помнить.
2. выполнение каждую секунду — это очень часто. Оно действительно надо? Может стоит уменьшить интервал до одного раза в минуту, а то и 5 — 10 минут...
3. запуск через `nohup` — не самый лучший вариант, если это не просто временная заплатка, которую скоро собираешься убрать, то, наверное, стоит делать это через систему инициализации (`systemd` в большинстве случаев сегодня).
4. использование и `php`, и `bash` — выглядит несколько неряшливо и создаёт небольшой оверхед. Возможно стоит остановиться на чём-то одном.

Comment: спасибо большое Вам за ответ. 4-й пункт Вы правы, исправлю.